# How can I hide inactive BuddyPress profiles?

Tags: buddypress

I am trying to hide a BuddyPress profile based on the time since last active. In other words, if the user goes inactive for a given length of time, I want to hide their profile. It is just a standard WordPress Site using the BuddyPress and bbPress plugins. There is no custom code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.